# How to make some code execute when the user leaves the current activity (Pressing back hardware button)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

As title says, how can I do it? I looked over the internet and it seems that you just can't do it.. Anyone knows how can it be done?

I mean, I know how to execute my code when the user presses a button that closes the activity, but what about the hardware back button?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use anyone from `onKeyDown` or `onBackPressed`  for controlling back key press

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //code
}
```

This will execute when the back button is used. If you want to run code even when the user navigates to another activity, or uses the home button, override `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code if you choose to do the onKeyDown/onKeyUp approach as ρяσѕρєя suggested.

```
// Sets functionality of the hard buttons on the device
@Override 
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Code
    }
    return true;
}
```